# In Qt Creator ncurses Error opening terminal: unknown

Tags: macos, ncurses

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    initscr();

    printw("Hello world");
    refresh();
    getch();
    endwin();
    return 0;
}
```

Preferences -> Environment -> System -> Terminal : **/usr/X11/bin/xterm -e**

.pro : **unix|win32: LIBS += -lncurses**

xterm Error : **Error opening terminal: unknown.**

Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to specify a TERM environment variable.